# Username validation using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am trying to validate the Username field in Vue using regex. I have a key down event on the textbox and on each key down the below method is called

```
userNameValidation(event) {
        if (!event.key.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

The issue with this regex is that it allows `.` and `_` at the start which I do not want.
I want the username to contain the alphabets, numbers, `.` and `_` and it should start with the alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

Use two characters sets, one at the start matching `[a-z]` one time, then the more permissive one you have matching zero or more times.

`/^[a-z][a-z0-9._]*$/i`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of validating on key press event. You can validate the username field on blur to match the whole regex in a single go.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    username: null
  },
  methods: {
    validateUserName() {
      if (!this.username.match(/^[a-z][a-z0-9._]*$/i)) {
        console.log('validation not passed!');
        event.stopPropagation();
      } else {
        console.log('validation passed!');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  User Name : <input type="text" v-model="username" @blur="validateUserName"/>
</div>
```